# HornetQ persistence on Jboss EAP 6.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, jboss7.x, hornetq

So I am using HonetQ on Jboss but I ran into an issue. Right now, if the jms messages arrive to our queues and suddendly there is a crash or a restart all our messages will be lost. I have read about enabling persitence on the queues but as I saw this parameter defaults to true. I have read several questions from other user like "where you using persistence ?" and "was persistence enabled?". What exactly is this persistence they refer to ? At queue level ? Or is there a higher level like a Hornet/Jboss configuration ?

Hope you can help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on jboss hornetQ is configured in the messaging domain of jboss configuration (standalone/domain.xml)

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">
        <hornetq-server>
            <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
            [...]
```

you can also set it on the message itself while posting it

```
messageProducer.send(objectMessage, DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT, priority, timeToLive);
```

also be sure that the queue is not configured with `durable` flag to false

```
<jms-queue name="myQueueName">
     <entry name="queue/myQueueName"/>
     <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/myQueueName"/>
</jms-queue>
```

see [What is the meaning of 'durable' attribute for JMS Queue in JBoss 7 with HornetQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816718/what-is-the-meaning-of-durable-attribute-for-jms-queue-in-jboss-7-with-hornetq)

Comment: The advice regarding the queue I already have it, and so do I on the standalone.xml. I will try to set it on the message. Any other idea ? The message keep disappearing from the queue on restart

Comment: maybe you're cleaning the data/messagingjournal directory ? How do you know that the message disappeared from the queue ? are you sure that it's not in 'in delivery' status?

Comment: I am consulting the queue data through management console of jboss. There I can see the message count as 1 or whatever and then after restart it is back on 0. how can I verify the "on delivery" ?

Comment: actually the field that increments and then goes back to 0 is "messages-added" on the data from the queue

Comment: yes it's normal, queue is re-created on server startup and message-added is so 0. your message should be either in message-count (currently in the queue) or deliveringCount (currently in delivery). For the delivery counter, note that consumers may fetch many message at a time (according to the consumer-windows-size parameter)

Comment: What you say makes sense but for some reason message-count was and remains 4, deliveringCount 0 and remains and the message-added was 1 and resetted to 0. Is there any limit on the message count that could be set to 4 ?

Comment: not on the message count itself but on the queue size (address-setting/max-size-bytes)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. It was exactly what you suggested, only needed to ensure the persistence was enabled on the queues individually. I was testing it wrongly !

Answer (score 1):

HornetQ persistance is configured with the `persistence-enabled` parameter in the the `hornetq-configuration.xml`. It should default to true, but maybe setting it explicitely will solve your issue.

Read more about it [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/persistence.html).

Comment: Tried it but the messages keep disappearing from the queues on restart. But thank you for your quick help